# Using GAE instances and GCE VM mixed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am building a news aggregator app, and the backend can be separated (mostly) in two logical parts:

1. Crawling, information extraction, parsing, clustering, storing...
2. Serving the user requests

What I would like to do is:
a) create a heavy Google Compute Engine VM Instance to do the crawling (since that isn't doable with a Google App Engine, because the instance RAM is relatively small) 
b) create a google app engine group of instances to serve the client requests which are light-weight and don't require much computational power per request

Is this possible to mix the two, Google App Engine and Google Compute Engine?

Or do I need to make the instances group on my own via GCE?

Comment: Yes, you can mix them. Why no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option you should explore is [App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/). *(disclaimer, I work at Google on App Engine)*

We allow you to build an App Engine application that has multiple modules.  Those modules will run on GCE virtual machines, which are managed by App Engine.  We auto-scale, auto-provision, etc.  Under the hood, we're actually provisioning a managed instance group and auto-scaler the same way you would with GCE (just no work).  You can also customize the CPU+Memory on the machine we run your app.

That way, both your front end and back end can run in the same project.  Check out:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! I hope my app launches soon :)

Comment: App Engine Flexible is awesome, but be aware that it _is_ technically in Beta and not covered by any SLA.